# How to get data out of {{ Form::select }} in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using PHP/Laravel.

I just created a select in my HTML and I am trying to get the data out of it when I submit the form. I followed this doc: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field

Here is my code I wrote:

`{{ Form::select('userLevels', ['All', 'Managers and Limited', 'Limited Only']) }}`

How can I get the selection when I submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller post method use-

```
$userLevels = Input::get('userLevels');
```

Or you could use -

```
$userLevels = $request->input('userLevels');
```

To go further deep into this topic, see Laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: Now here is a tricky one, what if I want to set the value of `$userLevels` in my controller after I get it from `Input::get('userLevels');` and it appear in my `Form::select`?

Comment: Does that make sense? Haha

Comment: $userLevels = $your_new_value;

Comment: you need to make sure that new value is available in your select array values.

Answer (score 0):

on the controller, you can use :

```
function index (Request $req){
  $userLevelsValue = $req->userLevels
  //do something with it

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject \Illuminate\Http\Request Class in your method. 
Then you can access your any input within that method. You can use diffrent ways like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $userLevels = $request->input('userLevels');

   //OR

   $userLevels = $request->get('userLevels');

   //OR

   $userLevels = $request->input('userLevels');

   //OR

   $userLevels = $request->userLevels;

   //OR

   $userLevels = request()->get('userLevels'); // for specific version only
}
```

Also you can get all inputs something like this:

```
$inputs = $request->all();
```

Good Luck